# How to secure Tensorflow in Vespa?

Tags: tensorflow, vespa

According to the Tensorflow documentation, it is important to secure TF by isolating it properly: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/SECURITY.md

However, I don’t see a mention of that on the Vespa security documentation: https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/securing-your-vespa-installation.html

In the above Vespa page, there are guidelines for protecting Vespa from the outside world, but not for protecting Vespa from TF. Perhaps the TF isolation is already handled properly out of the box, as recommended in the TF documentation, but that is not clearly spelled out.

On Vespa’s TF documentation, at the bottom, it says that not all TF operations are supported: https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/tensorflow.html

I wonder if operation limitations are part of Vespa’s threat prevention strategy, or if it is for another reason. Regardless of the reason, I would be curious to understand how operation restrictions have been implemented in Vespa.

Any insight regarding TF security in Vespa would be appreciated!

-F

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vespa translates TensorFlow graphs to [Vespa tensor expressions](https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/reference/tensor.html) at configuration time. These are evaluated using Vespa's own runtime. Since no TensorFlow code is involved at serving time there are no security issues related to TensorFlow.